# Concatenar varias celdas si contienen un texto de otra celda

Tags: excel

Necesito concatenar datos de una columna siguiendo el criterio de solo concatenar aquellas celdas que tengan cierto texto

La siguiente tabla es lo que necesito:

```
_______ A _____ B __________C                                           
1 _____ESD_____X______GABINETE ESD                                           
2 _____TOMA___X ______CONSOLA SCD                                           
3______DCS____ X______ GABINETE 3 ESD
```

> Nota. Los "_" de lo anterior son solo para intentar dar formato de tabla al ejemplo

Lo que requiero es buscar en la columna C todas las celdas que tengan el texo de la celda A1, para el ejemplo expuesto, seria buscar el texto `ESD` en todas las celdas de la columna C y concatenar las celdas que si lo contengan con cualquier separador p.e. "`,` ". Quedando en este caso la celda B1 con el resultado

Para este ejemplo, sería `GABINETE ESD, GABINETE 3 ESD`.

Los datos de la columna C son muchos mas datos de los de la columna A y B.

Comment: El ejemplo de datos que has puesto es confuso. ¿No puedes poner algo mejor? ¿Un pantallazo? O edita tu pregunta, y crea una tabla que podamos copiar y pegar.

Answer (score 0):

**Fórmula**

```
=UNIRCADENAS(", ";FALSO;FILTRAR($C:$C;SI.ERROR(HALLAR($A1;$C:$C);0)>0;{""}))
```

> - No funciona en veriones previas a Excel 365
> - Uso `;` como delimitador de parámetros, cambiar por `,` si es tu caso.

---

**Explicado** (de adentro para afuera)

1. Al usar `FILTRAR()`, nos permite utilizar matrices dinámicas. Por eso podemos usar `HALLAR()` sobre toda la fila C

   ```
   HALLAR($A1;$C:$C)
   ```

   Busca el texto de `$A1` dentro de toda la columna C. Si lo encuentra, devuelve la posición en la que encontró a cada uno.
2. Si no lo encuentra, da error, y lo convertimos en `0`

   ```
   SI.ERROR(HALLAR($A1;$C:$C);0)
   ```
3. Solamente los valores de esta matriz que sean mayores a `0` nos interesan, entonces usamos eso para filtrar toda la columna

   ```
   FILTRAR($C:$C;SI.ERROR(HALLAR($A1;$C:$C);0)>0;{""})
   ```

   Con esto, obtuvimos una matriz con todos los valores que tienen el texto.
4. Usamos `UNIRCADENAS()` para concatenar todos los valores que obtuvimos con comas. Con eso llegamos a la fórmula del principio.

[image: captura]